# The cause of REDIS Spikes?

Tags: redis

I have a new client is experiencing REDIS spikes and it is reflected in NewRelic

[image]

This is the 2nd call with this same problem this week and I am wondering if there is a good solution to REDIS slowness and site slowness?

Is clearing the REDIS cache on a daily or weekly basis a good practice?

Comment: is it remote or local?

Comment: It is local to the box

Comment: have you tried this page to debug your issue http://redis.io/topics/latency  and yes you can comment all `save`, and restart redis.

Answer (score 0):

Latency spike can be caused by a few things.  Mostly its caused by BGSAVE saving to disk.  Do you have BGSAVE enabled? What hardware are you running on?